# SimpleJdbcCall parameters not inserting null as NULL value

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

I'm calling an stored procedure in an MySql database

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_1` (IN in_param1 VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO t_1 (field1) VALUES (in_param1);
END
```

with a `SimpleJdbcCall` object:

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource);
jdbcCall.withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();
jdbcCall.withProcedureName(procedureName);

String paramValue = "new value";

MapSqlParameterSource map = new MapSqlParameterSource();
jdbcCall.addDeclaredParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR));
map.addValue("in_param1", paramValue, Types.VARCHAR);

SqlParameterSource sqlParameterSource = map;

jdbcCall.execute(sqlParameterSource);
```

It works fine except when the `paramValue` variable is null:

```
String paramValue = null;
```

In that case, the field has "null" text instead of a NULL value in the database.

Has anyone any idea about how do I have to create the parameter to send a real NULL value to the database?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
map.addValue("in_param1", paramValue, Types.NULL);
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion (`java.sql.Types.NULL`) and the result is the same: a "null" text in the field.

Comment: I was using an older version of the jdbc library. Thanks for your help @konstantin